# How to debug WCF service in Vs2012 as a normal code?

Tags: wcf

During debugging of WCF in vs2012 it throws the below exception;

I am using Vs2012 IIS7.5 and Windows7. The service is hosted on iis.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How can i debug WCF service?

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below line to the code.

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

and start debugging when asked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Attach to Process" dialog and attach to the IIS worker process (`w3wp.exe`). Go to the "Exceptions" dialog and tell it to throw on all exceptions. Then, if an exception occurs, it will break into the debugger at that point.

I also recommend that you consider catching exceptions that occur within the service and log them to the event log, with as much diagnostic data as you can. In my experience, I can usually identify the cause purely by looking at the exception stack trace. If I can do that then I don't have to waste time debugging. Have a look at the [`[ExceptionShielding]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664738%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) attribute from the Enterprise Library for an easy way to add error logging to all your service methods.